# how to use openfiledialog in autocad using vb.net for dll application

Tags: vb.net, autocad-plugin

how to use openfiledialog in auctocad using vb.net in a dll application for opening a file. Because no forms i used in the dll application. i am using imports autodesk.autocad.windows in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use:

```
var pfo = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput.PromptFileOptions(" message");

//add filter

var pfno = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.GetFileNameForOpen(pfo);
```

This is c# so you will need to transpose.